# Is it possible to use XML Message in JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, xml, web-services

I’m working on a project that involves both XML and JavaScript. I have some information which is described using XML and it is in a separate file; and this file is used by the module I created using JavaScript. The XML file is imported as XML DOM and it is used in an HTML file, at the client end, after the HTML file calls the JavaScript function.

Recently I heard about XML messaging and it is widely used in web services. But I don’t have the clue if I can use XML message instead of having my information only stored in XML file.  My intent is, I want to receive XML message similar to the XML file so I want the JavaScript module to listen to the XML message when it is arrived. Or did I perceive the concept of XML message wrongly?

So I would be happy if anyone points me on how I use XML message in JavaScript or if there is any workaround.

Thank you

Comment: You can use XML parser for parsing xml response coming from server

Answer (score 0):

The XML should be treated as a stream of data wherever it comes from, so yes it's entirely possible to read it some a source other than a file.

With regards to XML messaging, that normally involves messaging middle-ware like [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) or [IBM-MQ](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/ibm-mq), neither of which traditionally supported connections from JavaScript.

However, [web-sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) have changed this as they provide full-duplex communication required to push messages to a consumer.  Both [ActiveMQ (with STOMP or MQTT)](http://activemq.apache.org/websockets.html) and [IBM-MQ (with MQTT)](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mm.tc.doc/tc10110_.htm) now support sending and receiving messages from JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will look into ActiveMQ and IBM-MQ.